# Git Fetch not updating tracking branches in 'packed-refs'

Tags: git, github

Here is what I have done.

1. I have made a new commit in GitHub
2. Did "git fetch" in my local machine

**Expectation:**

Tracking branches would be updated, but local branches would remain as is.

**What I observed:**

As per what I read online, git tracking-branches are stored in "packed-refs" file in .git folder. They are still pointing to the old commits.

Please note that the fetch operation is successful.

**My question :** Why are the tracking branches in "packed-refs" not updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee when or if references are stored unpacked or packed, or if some future version of Git will store them in some third way (e.g., a real database).  You should generally not look at the files inside the `.git` directory (except to satisfy curiosity), but rather use the provided APIs (e.g., `git rev-parse`).

The more interesting question is whether, when the remote repository acquires updated branches, the `git fetch` prints out updates:

```
$ git fetch
[various messages ending with the "From <url>" part, snipped]
   dc8c8deaa6..e4a4b31577  maint      -> origin/maint
   69fb817120..8ac04bfd24  next       -> origin/next
 + a5b07a7eda...3df86c6a86 seen       -> origin/seen  (forced update)
```

If these updates *are not* getting printed, `git fetch` did not update anything.  In that case, the next interesting thing is what `remote.origin.fetch` is set to, assuming the name of the remote is `origin`:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If your `remote.origin.fetch` (or `remote.remote.fetch`) line is different, what does it contain and why?

Comment: How do I prove someone that tracking branches are updated when I do 'git fetch'?

Comment: `git reflog --pretty=%gd\ %gs --date=iso origin/master`

Comment: The command shows that a fetch has happened. But, how can I prove that tracking branches are updated?

Comment: I am convinced with the answer, so upvoted. It seems that after I do the fetch, git has created a file with the name 'feature1' under 'refs' folder, and there it stored the Hash of the latest commit. However, the packed-refs file is still pointing to the old commit.

So, I guess. I shouldn't be too concerned about how git manages it internally. Somehow, it does update the tracking branch (I guess) but it's none of my business to care about it.

Answer (score 2):

@toreks's advice is good: use and trust the git commands unless you've got concrete, articulable reasons not to. "I'm curious how it currently works" works for me, though, so: Git checks individual files before looking in `packed-refs`. That way looking up any single ref doesn't have to deal with 7420 packed refs just to find the one tracking branch you're after.